# Recursive ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

In regard to the following function, which I've rewritten a dozen times over the last hour:

```
function show_history() {
    $('.job.collapsed').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('.bottom').load('expand.php', function(){
            $('.job.expanded').click(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('expanded');
                $(this).addClass('collapsed');
                $(this).children('.bottom').html('');
                $(show_history);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Which I initially call as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').load('jobs.php', show_history);
});
```

The 1st time I click a '.job', 1 request is sent to 'expand.php'

The 2nd click also sends 1 request to 'expand.php', despite the '.job' not having the '.collapsed' class.

The 3rd click sends 2 requests, the 4th sends 3 requests, the 5th sends 6 requests, the 6th sends 9 requests, the 7th sends 18 requests, the 8th sends 27 requests, etc.

I would like it send 1 request when clicking a collapsed job, and no requests when I click an expanded job.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

The solution I used, based on @mblase75's suggestion:

```
function show_history() {
    $('.job.collapsed').live('click',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
        $(this).children('.bottom').load('expand.php');
    });
    $('.job.expanded').live('click',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).addClass('collapsed');
        $(this).children('.bottom').html('');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your `.click` out of the callback and replace it with a `.live("click")` handler:

```
   $('.job.expanded').live('click',function() {
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        $(this).addClass('collapsed');
        $(this).children('.bottom').html('');
        $(show_history);
   });
   $(this).children('.bottom').load('expand.php');
```

Comment: This set my on the right track. Separated the the `.job.expanded` and `.job.collapsed` events, set them both as `.live('click')` and stopped recalling the function. Works splendidly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a possible flaw in the code: ".job.expanded" is a class which, I assume, is given to more than one item in the same page. Therefore, $(this) will apply to ALL the items in the page

possible fix:

```
 $('.job.expanded').live('click',function() {
 var $thisID = $(this.id);
 $thisID.removeClass('expanded');
 $thisID.addClass('collapsed');
 $thisID.children('.bottom').html('');
 $(show_history);
 });
```

Oh yes, I have lost a bunch of hair on similar code fixing myself and hope have saved you some of your own.....